# rpath or LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains $HOME

Tags: gcc, build, shared-libraries, rpath

Is this possible that RPATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to a path contains environment variable like $HOME?  so that when the binary executes in different machines, it could results in an user-specific search path.

Comment: Of course. If the user isn't an admin, or is confining package installations / development to their home directory, a `$HOME/lib` or `$HOME/local/lib` might be the preferred location. Versioning issues and `-rpath` options aside, it may also result in the use of local libraries for dynamic linking / loading rather than system-wide libraries.

Comment: But I tried the RPATH contains $Home, but it doesn't work